# How to fixed 'ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().' when & is used

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I want to reassign values based on multiple columns conditions, but the `ValueError` appears. I used `&` instead of `and`, which was often the answer to solve such error. My goal and codes are as following:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. 
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I want to recode `YearsInCanada == Age`  if `CountryBorn == Canada` and `YearsInCanada == None`

```
df
Age    CountryBorn    YearsInCanada
87     NaN            77      
67     Canada         67
29     US             7
26     US             10
22     US             12
35     Canada         NaN
45     Canada         NaN

expected output
Age    CountryBorn    YearsInCanada
87     NaN            77      
67     Canada         67
29     US             7
26     US             10
22     US             12
35     Canada         35
45     Canada         45
```

My following codes showed the `ValueError`

```
    if df.loc[(df['YearsInCanada'] == None) & (df['CountryBorn'] == 'Canada')]:
        df['YearsInCanada'] == df['Age']

    else:
        df['YearsInCanada'] == df['YearsInCanada']
```

Thanks

Comment: why is the last value 35? shouldnt it be 45?

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks for pointing it out, a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.YearsInCanada=np.where((df['YearsInCanada'].isna()) & (df['CountryBorn'] == 'Canada'),\
                      df.YearsInCanada.fillna(df.Age),df.YearsInCanada)
print(df)

   Age CountryBorn  YearsInCanada
0   87         NaN           77.0
1   67      Canada           67.0
2   29          US            7.0
3   26          US           10.0
4   22          US           12.0
5   35      Canada           35.0
6   45      Canada           45.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(df['YearsInCanada'] == None) & (df['CountryBorn'] == 'Canada')]
```

This returns a (dervied) data frame.  `if` requires a Boolean expression.

If you're trying to make a vectorized assignment, you have to code this as a Pandas action + filter, not a Python `if`.